# Regex type as a parameter in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, function, parameters

The function is as follow:

```
def user_regex(regex_type, regex, test_string):
        my_regex = re.regex_type(regex, test_string)
        #...
```

Which cause this error:

> AttributeError at /
>
> module 're' has no attribute 'regex_type'

Of course the user chooses between findall, sub etc. when the function is called in my script.

Comment: What is ``regex_type``? Is it a string, as in ``"findall"``, or an actual regex "type", as in ``re.findall``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's a string

Comment: If you want to call `re.match` from inside the function, you don't need to (and preferably shouldn't) pass the string `"match"`; you should just pass the function `re.match` itself. `def user_regex(regex_func, regex, test_string): my_regex = regex_func(regex, test_string) ...`, then `x = user_regex(re.match, "f.*", "foo")`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, post it as an answer and I'll accept it